# How to set text color for my d3 chart title?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have my d3 chart title, text append on the svg as per below:

```
svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", (width / 2))             
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
    .style("font-size", "14px")
    .text(text);
```

reference [here](http://www.d3noob.org/2012/12/adding-axis-labels-to-d3js-graph.html)

But I would like to set the text color to some other color. Is that possible?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

I found out the way to set the text color is

```
.style('fill', 'darkOrange')
```

Answer (score 3):

In Version 7 of D3 for others coming across this in more recent times, do it with

```
.attr("fill", color)
```

E.g.

```
const svg = d3.create("svg")
                        .attr("width", width)
                        .attr("height", height)
                        .attr("viewBox", [-marginLeft, -marginTop, width, height])
                        .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto; height: intrinsic;")
                        .attr("fill", "black") 
                        .attr("font-size", 20) 
                        .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                        .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
```